# In TypeScript, how do I break triple-slash directive to several lines?

Tags: typescript

Consider a triple-slash directive in a TypeScript file:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="tpl!components/incidents-variable-line-filter/incidents-variable-line-filter.html" name="template" />
```

I have a setting for TSLint to reject lines longer than 120 characters, and TSLint complains about the line above. Is there any way to break triple-slash directive to multiple lines, so that I can keep the `max-line-length` setting for TSLint?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother, it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

You should be able to keep tslint working by adding the following on the line before.

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
```

(or any of the other tslint:disable incantations)